# File name encoding wrong in KDE, but correct in GTK/tty1/

Tags: kde, filenames, character-encoding

I'm on a new Linux (installed yesterday). When I access files from old partitions their file names have incorrect encoding (Ã¤ instead of ä, same for other umlauts) inside KDE apps like dolphin and konsole.

All characters look correct when I display them in tty and GTK apps. (And they obviously also did so on the old system.)

How can I make KDE4 show the file names correctly?

Comment: You probably needed `LANG=*.UTF-8` in the environment such as `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Now can you tell me why StackExchange is giving me a four year old question (which I just noticed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Moved answer from May 2012 from question to here)*

So now I «fixed» this by re-installing the system. No idea what the problem was.

**To get the keyboard right** everywhere (tty, KDM login screen, KDE) I had to run

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales       # Kept only (de_CH|en_US|ru_RU).UTF-8
                               # Selected de_CH.UTF-8 as default
dpkg-reconfigure console-data  # Selected German (Switzerland) 
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration 
                               # Selected my 105-key Cherry CyMotion Xpert 
                               # AltGr on right Alt, no Compose key
```

Running keyboard-configuration first does not work since those settings are specific to the default keyboard selected in locales; for en_* e.g. there is no AltGr and no compose key.

(Debian based system.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the file encoding of the partitions in question, and set that encoding in fstab for the partition. I am assuming that the partitions in question are NTFS or FAT from a Windows setup. What language was Windows in? German?